# Is it possible to insert un-formatted data for money data type in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, datatypes, money

By default, PostgreSQL's `money` data type inserts values with currency code and grouping. I have observed that it always inserts values with `$`.

1. How can I insert locale specific values?
2. How can I insert values with my own digit grouping and decimal grouping formats?
3. How can I read unformatted data?
4. Why is PostgreSQL's money data type different than MS SQL's money data type?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 1. How can I insert locale specific values?

Set **[`LC_MONETARY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/locale.html#AEN38545)** accordingly. (Only affects the `money` type and some monetary details in formatting output!) You can do this as permanent default for your whole DB cluster in `postgresql.conf`, just for the current session with [`SET`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-set.html) or for the transaction only with [`SET LOCAL`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-set.html). ([Or in several other ways.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9067777/939860))

Demo on a Windows machine:

```
BEGIN;
CREATE TEMP TABLE mdemo(id serial, m money);

SET LOCAL lc_monetary = 'German_Austria.1252';
INSERT INTO mdemo(m) VALUES ('123.45');

SET LOCAL lc_monetary = 'English_US.1252';
INSERT INTO mdemo(m) VALUES ('123.45');
TABLE mdemo;

 id |     m
----+------------
  1 | $12,345.00
  2 |    $123.45


ROLLBACK;  -- to clean up
```

As you can see the string literal '123.45' was interpreted according to the current setting of `LC_MONETARY`. In Austria, the dot (`.`) serves as group separator and `,` is the decimal point. While in the USA it's the other way round.

It's important to find correct locale names. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/locale.html)

> What locales are available on your system under what names depends on
>   what was provided by the operating system vendor and what was
>   installed. On most Unix systems, the command `locale -a` will provide a
>   list of available locales. Windows uses more verbose locale names,
>   such as `German_Germany` or `Swedish_Sweden.1252`, but the principles are the same.

---

> 2. How can I insert values with my own digit grouping and decimal grouping formats?

Use [`to_number()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-TABLE) to produce a `numeric` value from the string literal, which can in turn be cast to `money`.

Say,  you have this literal: `'12,454.8-'`:
2 digits, `,` as group separator, 3 digits, `.` as decimal point, 1 digit, pending sign. This does not work:

```
SELECT money '12,454.8-';
```

Works:

```
SELECT to_number('12,454.8-', '99,999.9S')::money
```

Since we are reading in a general *number* the more general setting for [**`LC_NUMERIC`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/locale.html#AEN38545) applies for the import while the setting for `LC_MONETARY` still dictates how the result is ***displayed***! The cast from `numeric` to `money` is locale-agnostic (immutable). Don't get confused.

And the pattern in the 2nd parameter is tricky, too. Symbols like `,` and `.` are taken literally and interpreted according to C locale (no locale), while patterns (you could use `'99G999D9S'`, too) are interpreted according to the current locale.

[I suggested clarifications to the manual on pgsql-docs.](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/CAGHENJ45ymd%3DGOCu1vwV9u7GmCR80_5tW0fP9C_gJKbruGMHvQ%40mail.gmail.com#CAGHENJ45ymd=GOCu1vwV9u7GmCR80_5tW0fP9C_gJKbruGMHvQ@mail.gmail.com)

---

> 3. How can I read unformatted data?

You can *read* it, but you can hardly cast this to any numeric type without a minimum of information about its format.

---

I still would rather not use the data type `money`. Narrow, quirky specification. Use `numeric` to cover all bases. Or just `integer` signifying cents, performs better. See:

- [PostgreSQL: Which Datatype should be used for Currency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15726535/postgresql-which-datatype-should-be-used-for-currency/15729573)

Answer (score 3):

I would strongly recommend to **not** use the `money` data type.

All your problems derive from the limits of the money data type.

Using `numeric()` is a much better alternative. If you need to store values for *different* currencies it's the **only** choice you have anyway (you will need another column that stores the currency of that value).

---

To answer your questions:

> *How can I insert locale specific values?*

You can't. The formatting (at least in psql) is always done based on the locale of the client.

> *How can I insert values with my own digit grouping and decimal grouping formats?*

You can't. Numbers (including numbers in a `money` column) are always stored **without** any formatting. The formatting is done based on the client's locale. If you need that use `numeric` and apply the formatting in your application or us `to_char()`

> *why PostgreSQL's money datatype is different with MS-SQL money datatype?*

Because there is no standard for a "money" data type.

> *How can I read un-formatted data?*

I don't think this is easily possible, as the formatting is done by the libpq library. There might be low level API calls to do that, but definitely not through SQL. Again using `numeric` is the better choice if you need that.