# Handling differences between MS-SQL and PostgreSQL money datatypes

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, pgadmin, money

This is a follow-up/ to my previous question [Is it possible to insert un-formatted data for money data type in PostgreSQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/183964/is-it-possible-to-insert-un-formatted-data-for-money-data-type-in-postgresql/184155#184155)

1. I could read money data by typecasting it into numeric

   ```
    SELECT '52093.89'::money::numeric
   ```

   Will it give inconsistent data, rounded etc.. ?
2. As per ISO standard, the `money` datatype size is (19,4) but why PostgreSQL returns size as 2147483647? Is this size locale dependent?
3. Is it a good idea to use the `money` datatype to store/retrieve locale specific values? If not, when is the `money` datatype best suitable?

I have to use the `money` datatype for certain cases. My worry is will I get any problems if I treat `money` datatype values as decimal values?

I don't bother about locale specific values such as symbol, digit, and decimal grouping etc.. Can I store money datatype values as per `lc_monetary` settings and reading by typecasting it to `numeric`?

Comment: Why do you "have" to use the `money` type? If you plan to treat those values as numeric, then you could simply use `numeric` to start with.

Comment: Not the clearest of questions, but certainly not "off topic".

Comment: "As per ISO standard" which ISO standard?

Comment: There is no `money` type in SQL standard, as far as I know.

Answer (score 6):

In Postgres, the cast from `money` to `numeric` is exact, immutable and does not round.

[In SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179882.aspx) the data type `MONEY` uses 8 bytes to store a values in any currency in the numeric range from -922337203685477.5808 to 922337203685477.5807.
Matches `numeric(19,4)`.

[In PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-money.html) the data type `money` also occupies 8 bytes but the allowed range is -92233720368547758.08 to +92233720368547758.07. Same precision, but different scale by default (without `LC_MONETARY` setting other than 'C') - only two fractional digits.
Matches `numeric(19,2)`.

But, [quoting the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-money.html):

> The fractional precision is determined by the database's `lc_monetary` setting.

I updated the tag info for [money](/questions/tagged/money) accordingly.

As @a_horse commented (repeatedly), `money` is not defined by the SQL standard.

And it's pretty much [consensus around here](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_money) to stay away from the `money` data type if you can.